# Trying to Secure MySQL Replication

Tags: ssh, mysql

I'm  trying to do Secure MySQL Replication on my VPS with Ubuntu 14.04.
I follow these steps (read only Step 1: Setup SSH Tunneling):
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-mysql-replication-using-ssh-on-a-vps

The problem occurs when I try to create the tunnel on my Slave machine, when I run:

```
ssh -L 33061:localhost:3306 tunneluser@1.1.1.1 -f -N
```

I get this respone:

```
This account is currently not available.
```

I did some tests, for example if I don't execute this line:

```
usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin tunneluser
```

it create the tunnel but it throws a message "–N: not found".
If i try to connect from Slave to Master whit

```
ssh 'tunneluser@1.1.1.1' //before to usermod -s /sbin/nologin tunneluser
```

it works, so my keys are correct.

First time when I tried this it had been working fine, but now I can't reproduce it againg. I'm using the same images of my VPS's, I follow same steps, there is no difference in the environmnet, what cloud be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake.
The problem was in MS Word, I saved all commands in a doc file and just copy and paste them. MS Word does regular - in longer – in some cases. So, this longer dash break my last command:

```
ssh -L 33061:localhost:3306 tunneluser@1.1.1.1 -f -N
```